# import pywinauto occur exception

Tags: pywinauto

I'm using Python 3.4.3
I install pywinauto use pip
] pip install pywinauto

then write down,

```
>>>from pywinauto import application
```

but can't work,and something info like below

```
>>> from pywinauto.application import Application
2017-01-24 23:56:20,849 INFO: Imported existing <module 'comtypes.gen' from 'D:\
\IDE\\Python\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\comtypes\\gen\\__init__.py'>
2017-01-24 23:56:20,850 INFO: Using writeable comtypes cache directory: 'D:\IDE\
Python\Python34\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen'
```

Is this mean I installed unsuccessful ?
then I write something ,occur exception like:

```
>>> app = application.Application.start('notepad.exe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cmd_line'
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import pywinauto first time, module `comtypes` outputs some warnings. It's not an error, but we will hide it in coming pywinauto 0.6.1.

The second line is incorrect because `start(...)` is not a static method. You need to create `Application` object first: `app = Application().start('notepad.exe')`. So in your case `'notepad.exe'` argument has been treated as `self`.

P.S. I'd recommend [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) written specially for 0.6.0, it explains some new features.